# Has anyone used C# with a Sales Logix database?

Tags: c#, .net, database, saleslogix

Has anyone used C# with a Sales Logix database?

Comment: How about rewording the question to ask something specific?

Comment: Instead of posting several questions of the form "has anyone used X with a Sales Logix database" why not post 1 question asking what language to use to interface with a sales logix database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  I have.

(Not the most interesting answer on SOB today, but that's what the question asked...)

Comment: Could you give me any recommendation on how to get started? Connecting to the database, how it differs from a sql db, etc? Thanks

Comment: There's nothing special ... they just install their schema into a regular SQL Server or Oracle server.  See for example the system requirements at 

http://www.dmcsoftware.co.uk/Saleslogix/slxspecifications.aspx

(Unless we're talking about two different SalesLogix's?  If so, sorry!)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  I rewrote a History tab that worked better and faster than the original Best/Sage built-in tab version using datagridviews in C#.  It was a .NET plugin and I used Ryan Farley's instructions for getting it to work in SLX 6.x.  In SLX 7.x you can use C# and VB.NET natively for building plug in components.